# Redirect only Blog posts to new

Tags: redirect

I have Copied over all blog posts to a new domain.
I would like to create redirects for all blog posts to new URL but keep the pages as they are.
Is there a wildcard Solution for this?

Comment: How are your permalinks (for posts) set up?

Comment: It's set as custom post name :
/%postname%/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to do is, check if it is a post via [`is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/), get the current URL (or at least that part after the domain), and redirect to the new domain.

Here I am using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to easily differentiate between host, path, etc.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_redirect_posts_to_new_page');
function wpse_redirect_posts_to_new_page() {
  // if this is not a single post or not of type post, do nothing
  if ( ! is_single() || get_post_type() != 'post')
    return;

  $url = parse_url(get_the_permalink());
  $newdomain = 'https://www.example.com'; // no trailing slash!
  wp_redirect($newdomain . $url['path']);
  exit;
}
```